# confused about what 'Series' is?

Tags: real-analysis

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence then series generated by $(x_n)$ is the sequence $(s_k)$ defined by

$s_1 = x_1$

$s_2 = x_1 + x_2$

$\;\;\;\;\;\vdots$

$s_k = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k$

$\;\;\;\;\;\vdots$

---

Does this mean that series is sequence $s_k$ ?

So series is a special case of sequence?

Thanks.

Comment: this is very informal, but given an infinite sequence, a series is the sum of the terms in that sequence

Comment: You are correct.  A series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}$ can be identified with the new sequence $(s_n)$.

Comment: @user84413 Sorry but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is a number, not a series.

Comment: @Did I am using the same notation as Wikipedia:  For any sequence $\{a_n\}$ of rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, functions thereof, etc., the associated series is defined as the ordered formal sum

    $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots$ .

Comment: @user84413 Well, what can I say? You should not.

Answer (score 2):

The most convincing definition of a series might be as *a pair of sequences* $(x_n)$ and $(s_n)$ related as you explain in your post. Otherwise, a series would be just a sequence $(s_n)$ such that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ whose $(s_n)$ is the sequence of partial sums. Every sequence $(s_n)$ is such hence the concept of series would become empty, however some texts do adopt this (in my opinion, inferior) convention.

Anyway, a fact to remember is that a series is not uniquely determined by its sum, for example the two series 
$$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{2^n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{41}{(42)^n}
$$ are not equal although they both sum to $1$. One often writes 
$$\sum_{n\geqslant1}x_n\qquad\text{or even}\qquad\sum_{n}x_n
$$ for the series (a sequence or, more rigorously, as explained above, a pair of sequences) and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n
$$ for its sum (a number).

While at it, one might as well mention that a sequence is *a function*, for example, the real-valued sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is the function $u:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ defined by $u(n)=x_n$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Each $s_k$ is given by a series of $x_k$. However, the collection $\{s_k\}$ is a sequence.

A series is just a summation of objects belonging to a sequence. You can have a sequence whose elements are individually determined by a series. You can then take a series of a sequence whose elements are individually determined by a series. And so on....

Comment: "the set {sk} is a sequence." Pleeease, a sequence is not a set.

Comment: @did *ahem* That's the third time I've done that recently. It's because my local tex shortcut for enclosing things in braces is `\SET` so I just mentally go there without thinking >.<